# OSX 9 Mavericks - Homebrew - g++ 4.8 - link fails: Undefined symbol "__istype(int, unsigned long)"

Tags: macos, homebrew

```
g++-4.8 -o block_test block_test.o Block.o MemRef.o CI_Metadata.o ConnectMxctl.o Log.o BLog.o -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -g 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__istype(int, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::ctype<char>::is(unsigned long, char) const in block_test.o
      std::ctype<char>::is(unsigned long, char) const in ConnectMxctl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The closest thing to a solution I've found from Googling is to run `xcode-select --install`.  This actually succeeded once, I think; subsequent attempts fail because it is "not currently available from the software update server."

xcode is installed and up to date, including the command line utilities.  Also, I used homebrew to install g++-4.8, so things are located in /usr/local/Cellar/.  Other suggestions have been to (compile? link?) /opt/local/lib/gcc48/libstdc++.a, which I changed to /usr/local/Cellar/gcc48/4.8.1/gcc/lib/libstdc++.a because I'm using brew, not MacPorts -- but I haven't figured out where that belongs.

Comment: Did you compiled the object files on the same machine?

Comment: I think you need to add some more context, like what you are building, how you are building it, and how to reproduce it.  It's probably a mixup of compiler and standard library, but it's hard to say more without seeing more details.

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce the problem and have submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues/347).